# SAP HANA Studio R Integration for Windows

Tags: sql, r, hana, rserve

How do I integrate SAP HANA Studio with Rserve in Windows? I want to run R code on SQL Script with other SQL statements.  I do not have access to Linux on my job and I am currently using Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You have this backwards.

There are two different integration scenarios for SAP HANA and R:

1. HANA -> R (via RServe)
2. R -> HANA (via ODBC or JDBC)

None of these scenarios involves HANA Studio as a part of the integration.
The first type of integration really is a setup task for the HANA administrator. Once the connection between the RServe and the HANA server is set up correctly, developers can build calculation models and procedure based on R code in the HANA development environment.

For the second type of integration R simply is a database client to SAP HANA and gets data via RODBC or RJDBC. No need to have access to the Linux (HANA) server for this. All you need is the client software installed on your local computer to connect to HANA.

Comment: Thank you so much Lars for your response. One more question, for the first type is linux a must?

Comment: Well, if you get RServe up and running on a Windows systems, then it probably will work as well. Haven't tested that.

Comment: How do I get Rserve up and running on a windows system? Most of the research articles that I found online are about installing it on a Linux system.

Comment: No idea @LearningHero, never tried that. But why do you need to do that in the first place? If you have a HANA system, then your HANA admin could help you with the RServe on Linux topic. If you want to use HANA Studio at home, you will still need a connection to this HANA server. Alternatively, you could use HANA Express in a VM on your Windows system. You just need to have enough RAM (min 16 GB) for that to work well.