# Importing data from SAP HANA/HANA Express in R

Tags: r, hana, sap-cloud-platform

I have data stored in HANA Express which would be imported in R for analysis. Just like SQL packages for R, Is there any R package specified for HANA express ? or any step by step process to integrate ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SAP Hana Studio R Integration for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332218/sap-hana-studio-r-integration-for-windows)

Comment: also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64756678/how-get-access-to-sap-sandbox-via-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121135/r-sap-hana-integration-with-odbc-for-windows), please use SO search before posting new question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [R machine learning client for SAP HANA](https://help.sap.com/doc/b64d3cac2f0b42be9ca9fc662715f36b/2021_2_QRC/en-US/docs/index.html). While this client offers a variety of functionalities to manage the lifecycle of ML models in SAP HANA, it also comes handy for non-ML related tasks.